# How can I fetch the number of all Sub-Sub-Entities?

Tags: core-data

A House has many Rooms. Each Room has many Windows.

[image]

Now i want the house to know the number of windows it has.

Sure, it is possible by looping through all rooms and count them manually.
But I guess it is possible (and more efficient) with a FetchRequest.

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a relationship between Houses and Windows, such that when you create a Window object and assign it to a room, assign it to the house as well.

Then you can just get the count of that relationship.

If you wanted to go the fetch route, you could do something with a predicate on Windows like: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"room IN %@", house.rooms"]`. This says to fetch all Windows where the room is one of the house's rooms.

Comment: Great, thank you!! I had tested this before but I always got 0 instances. Assigning them to the room was the key :-D